# Retrieving most frequent value for each group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I have:

```
AirlineName                                                                                          Departure_City No_of_DepartureCity Arrival_City No_of_ArrivalCity
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ------------------- ------------ -----------------
Air Asia                                                                                             MY             2                   JPN          2
Emirates Airlines                                                                                    MY             2                   JPN          2
Malaysia Airlines                                                                                    MY             2                   GER          2
Malaysia Airlines                                                                                    MY             1                   JPN          1
Air Asia                                                                                             MY             1                   KOR          1
```

This is what I want:

```
AirlineName                                                                                          Departure_City No_of_DepartureCity Arrival_City No_of_ArrivalCity
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ------------------- ------------ -----------------
Air Asia                                                                                             MY             2                   JPN          2
Emirates Airlines                                                                                    MY             2                   JPN          2
Malaysia Airlines                                                                                    MY             2                   GER          2
```

I have already written a query to retrieve the most frequent data for `Departure_City` and `Arrival_City`, but I can't make it grouped together and only show the most frequent data for each `AirlineName`.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT Airline.AirlineName, Flight_Schedule.Departure_City, COUNT(Flight_Schedule.Departure_City) AS No_of_DepartureCity, Flight_Schedule.Arrival_City, COUNT(Flight_Schedule.Arrival_City) AS No_of_ArrivalCity
FROM Airline
LEFT JOIN Aircraft ON Airline.AirlineID = Aircraft.AirlineID
LEFT JOIN Flight_Schedule ON Aircraft.AircraftID = Flight_Schedule.AircraftID
GROUP BY Airline.AirlineName, Flight_Schedule.Departure_City, Flight_Schedule.Arrival_City
ORDER BY COUNT(Flight_Schedule.Departure_City)DESC , COUNT(Flight_Schedule.Arrival_City) DESC
```

Comment: Have a look at ROW_NUMBER/RANK

Comment: @bk23 . . . Your sample data and your query have nothing to do with each other, making the question very hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Rank` or `Dense_rank` (If you want to select more than two rows having same number of cities) function

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ff8c8/2)

```
with CTE1 AS(
SELECT A.*,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AirlineName ORDER BY No_of_ArrivalCity desc) as rn 
FROM TABLE1 A)
SELECT * FROM CTE1 where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're grouping by lots of columns, instead of just 'AirlineName' it's grouping by all of the different values across those number of columns.

To return the number of AirlineName's and their frequency try this:

```
SELECT Airline.AirlineName, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT]
FROM Airline
GROUP BY Airline.AirlineName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you **need** the additional columns then your code is already correct, because of how you are grouping it and the individual values contained within the columns.